# Spot light hover effect on svg path

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have an svg with a few paths inside it. I want to create an hover effect of a spotlight on this svg such that only the area inside the path of a radius of 20px are highlighted on hover.
I have a codepen like for reference to what I am imagining- [text](https://codepen.io/Ayushi227/pen/zYbKOJx).

```
<svg width="1423" height="352" viewBox="0 0 1423 352" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M188.954 578.594C178.029 495.84 183.606 379.575 203.227 281.806C220.869 193.916 257.573 79.5688 332.252 33.9531C418.085 -18.4755 485.295 40.2998 550.288 97.1414C584.253 126.846 616.316 154.892 650.211 167.004C652.344 167.767 654.486 168.466 656.638 169.1C745.537 195.264 836.352 165.951 932.495 134.922C1006.07 111.178 1082.11 86.6354 1160.51 86.7372C1211.53 86.8069 1264.04 111.675 1308.37 156.756C1323.09 171.833 1336.39 188.226 1348.11 205.73C1426.73 322.292 1445.01 478.351 1394.7 603.304C1322.46 782.72 1057.48 881.997 607.11 898.37C467.424 903.458 359.763 868.569 287.12 794.692C221.606 728.061 197.781 642.391 189.372 581.69L187.822 581.898L187.403 578.801L188.954 578.594ZM1310.62 154.586C1282.57 126.061 1251.98 105.748 1219.69 94.2076C1200.72 87.3145 1180.7 83.7317 1160.52 83.6154C1081.61 83.5083 1005.32 108.134 931.54 131.95C835.858 162.831 745.493 191.996 657.52 166.103C621.886 155.608 588.116 126.073 552.363 94.8038C486.508 37.2065 418.42 -22.3429 330.623 31.2848C254.98 77.4895 217.926 192.687 200.166 281.192C180.356 379.885 174.819 497.394 186.064 580.559C194.365 641.966 218.249 729.391 284.863 797.141C357.986 871.506 466.444 906.616 607.227 901.494C801.361 894.433 962.636 871.892 1086.58 834.502C1251.54 784.732 1356.18 707.338 1397.6 604.475C1423.47 540.222 1431.74 467.078 1421.52 392.941C1412.12 324.866 1386.97 257.757 1350.71 203.985C1338.88 186.331 1325.46 169.796 1310.62 154.588" fill="url(#paint0_diamond_1354_44250)" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
<path d="M253.934 566.964C244.232 493.255 249.206 389.785 266.673 302.756C282.385 224.478 315.069 122.644 381.555 82.0344C457.928 35.3839 517.764 87.7171 575.634 138.329C605.89 164.792 634.469 189.789 664.706 200.594C666.611 201.276 668.523 201.901 670.443 202.47C749.702 225.795 830.64 199.672 916.329 172.018C981.856 150.87 1049.61 129.003 1119.44 129.095C1164.85 129.155 1211.59 151.291 1251.05 191.429C1251.05 191.429 1251.06 191.434 1251.06 191.437C1264.17 204.861 1276.01 219.457 1286.45 235.042C1356.46 338.848 1372.74 477.826 1327.94 589.109C1263.6 748.895 1027.56 837.316 626.355 851.908C501.954 856.426 406.074 825.356 341.376 759.556C283.091 700.281 261.863 624.097 254.352 570.061L252.803 570.271L252.383 567.173L253.934 566.964ZM1253.3 189.258C1228.29 163.823 1201.01 145.707 1172.22 135.416C1155.3 129.267 1137.45 126.07 1119.44 125.965C1049.1 125.873 981.115 147.816 915.365 169.038C830.149 196.543 749.659 222.52 671.322 199.467C639.6 190.125 609.526 163.821 577.692 135.975C518.972 84.6176 458.26 31.5176 379.923 79.3688C259.952 152.648 232.631 432.728 251.044 568.931C258.443 623.678 279.733 701.618 339.119 762.015C404.295 828.297 500.973 859.593 626.469 855.026C799.446 848.741 943.153 828.656 1053.61 795.333C1200.63 750.973 1293.91 681.981 1330.83 590.275C1376.01 478.061 1359.61 337.935 1289.04 233.288C1278.49 217.552 1266.53 202.813 1253.3 189.258Z" fill="url(#paint1_diamond_1354_44250)" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
<path d="M395.632 724.432C344.02 671.937 325.537 604.345 319.122 556.884C310.369 492.133 314.687 400.606 330.119 323.71C343.9 255.047 372.559 165.725 430.856 130.118C497.762 89.2473 550.226 135.127 600.96 179.497C627.538 202.744 652.633 224.695 679.197 234.19C680.874 234.791 682.556 235.339 684.242 235.835C753.858 256.324 824.917 233.39 900.15 209.111C957.646 190.553 1017.09 171.365 1078.36 171.444C1118.16 171.501 1159.14 190.911 1193.73 226.097C1205.23 237.873 1215.62 250.676 1224.77 264.346C1286.18 355.402 1300.47 477.308 1261.17 574.915C1204.73 715.079 997.628 792.638 645.6 805.444C536.488 809.408 452.387 782.152 395.632 724.432ZM1195.98 223.921C1174.01 201.577 1150.05 185.664 1124.75 176.623C1109.88 171.219 1094.19 168.409 1078.36 168.318C1016.6 168.234 956.922 187.499 899.198 206.13C824.436 230.26 753.82 253.052 685.127 232.835C657.338 224.658 630.954 201.581 603.027 177.153C551.437 132.033 498.095 85.382 429.225 127.445C323.862 191.807 299.857 437.718 316.025 557.302C322.525 605.391 341.217 673.85 393.369 726.888C450.601 785.092 535.5 812.571 645.718 808.563C797.559 803.037 923.703 785.407 1020.64 756.16C1149.75 717.21 1231.65 656.622 1264.07 576.081C1303.75 477.543 1289.34 354.492 1227.37 262.596C1218.11 248.774 1207.6 235.828 1195.98 223.921Z" fill="url(#paint2_diamond_1354_44250)" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
<path d="M383.894 543.708C376.641 488.099 380.408 410.201 393.563 344.655C405.413 285.606 430.056 208.794 480.154 178.194C537.607 143.102 582.692 182.54 626.295 220.681C649.19 240.704 670.799 259.6 693.69 267.782C695.136 268.299 696.588 268.772 698.047 269.201C758.023 286.854 819.211 267.105 883.989 246.2C933.45 230.235 984.591 213.728 1037.28 213.798C1071.48 213.844 1106.69 230.524 1136.42 260.764C1136.42 260.765 1136.42 260.765 1136.42 260.766C1136.42 260.767 1136.42 260.768 1136.42 260.769C1146.3 270.891 1155.23 281.896 1163.11 293.647C1215.92 371.953 1228.2 476.786 1194.4 560.723C1145.87 681.262 967.701 747.958 664.842 758.97C571.019 762.387 498.698 738.945 449.89 689.309C406.065 644.736 390.02 587.521 384.318 546.808L382.764 547.014L382.344 543.917L383.894 543.708ZM1138.67 258.592C1119.73 239.337 1099.08 225.624 1077.27 217.831C1064.45 213.171 1050.93 210.749 1037.28 210.67C984.1 210.6 932.719 227.183 883.031 243.221C818.726 263.977 757.985 283.583 698.929 266.203C675.074 259.189 652.393 239.353 628.38 218.351C585.974 181.257 537.941 139.242 478.528 175.525C387.771 230.964 367.084 442.712 381.005 545.675C386.605 587.101 402.711 646.076 447.629 691.756C496.914 741.882 570.035 765.547 664.955 762.095C969.161 751.035 1148.27 683.675 1197.31 561.89C1231.48 477.021 1219.07 371.044 1165.7 291.902C1157.72 279.997 1148.68 268.847 1138.67 258.592Z" fill="url(#paint3_diamond_1354_44250)" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
<path d="M448.874 532.078C438.045 448.177 455.966 271.168 529.46 226.276C577.442 196.969 615.153 229.953 651.624 261.851C670.818 278.638 688.948 294.498 708.185 301.371C709.402 301.807 710.623 302.205 711.847 302.566C762.19 317.38 813.5 300.82 867.823 283.286C909.245 269.915 952.083 256.088 996.202 256.144C1024.79 256.187 1054.23 270.137 1079.1 295.428L1079.1 295.431C1087.37 303.901 1094.85 313.111 1101.44 322.946C1145.65 388.502 1155.93 476.26 1127.64 546.525C1087.01 647.437 937.777 703.279 684.085 712.506C605.548 715.363 545.008 695.735 504.146 654.175C467.551 616.959 454.102 569.225 449.294 535.177L447.74 535.387L447.321 532.288L448.874 532.078ZM1081.35 293.257C1065.45 277.092 1048.11 265.579 1029.8 259.035C1019.03 255.121 1007.67 253.087 996.208 253.022C951.609 252.963 908.534 266.863 866.878 280.305C813.01 297.694 762.144 314.111 712.732 299.569C692.844 293.756 673.962 277.235 653.97 259.748L653.684 259.499C618.103 228.377 577.775 193.104 527.83 223.61C451.677 270.124 434.31 447.703 445.985 534.046C450.682 568.814 464.197 618.306 501.883 656.633C543.222 698.675 604.561 718.525 684.201 715.628C939.24 706.355 1089.41 649.855 1130.54 547.696C1159.21 476.494 1148.8 387.592 1104.03 321.201C1097.34 311.214 1089.74 301.86 1081.35 293.256" fill="url(#paint4_diamond_1354_44250)" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
<path d="M558.401 619.048C528.487 588.627 517.775 549.482 514.06 522C504.995 454.906 519.221 310.725 578.758 274.359C617.278 250.829 647.615 277.363 676.956 303.024C692.464 316.589 707.108 329.399 722.675 334.962C723.665 335.316 724.656 335.639 725.651 335.931C766.35 347.908 807.785 334.532 851.652 320.374C885.047 309.594 919.58 298.45 955.122 298.493C978.108 298.531 1001.78 309.751 1021.78 330.093C1021.78 330.093 1021.78 330.098 1021.79 330.099C1028.44 336.921 1034.46 344.337 1039.77 352.253C1075.38 405.053 1083.66 475.738 1060.87 532.329C1028.15 613.616 907.85 658.596 703.33 666.035C640.082 668.338 591.317 652.529 558.401 619.048ZM1024.03 327.921C1011.17 314.852 997.143 305.537 982.326 300.239C973.605 297.072 964.404 295.426 955.126 295.374C919.097 295.325 884.32 306.549 850.688 317.404C807.294 331.41 766.305 344.639 726.532 332.933C710.532 328.244 695.245 314.872 679.058 300.719C650.224 275.496 617.603 246.966 577.123 271.694C515.585 309.283 501.535 452.699 510.962 522.42C514.765 550.525 525.685 590.534 556.139 621.507C589.535 655.467 639.094 671.502 703.44 669.162C909.312 661.675 1030.55 616.034 1063.78 533.5C1086.94 475.968 1078.53 404.143 1042.36 350.509C1036.95 342.436 1030.81 334.875 1024.03 327.921Z" fill="url(#paint5_diamond_1354_44250)" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
<path d="M612.655 583.924C589.974 560.859 581.856 531.193 579.041 510.374C572.157 459.439 582.922 350.012 628.059 322.443C657.114 304.695 679.055 323.887 702.287 344.202C714.103 354.537 725.266 364.301 737.17 368.557C737.928 368.826 738.69 369.077 739.455 369.303C770.511 378.441 802.071 368.256 835.483 357.472C860.848 349.285 887.075 340.816 914.044 340.849C931.419 340.876 949.328 349.368 964.466 364.76C969.512 369.933 974.075 375.556 978.097 381.56C1005.11 421.611 1011.39 475.219 994.11 518.139C969.288 579.794 877.93 613.923 722.573 619.575C674.611 621.317 637.63 609.324 612.655 583.924ZM966.703 362.586C956.892 352.605 946.174 345.492 934.855 341.444C928.184 339.021 921.146 337.762 914.049 337.722C886.593 337.683 860.12 346.228 834.523 354.492C801.582 365.124 770.468 375.167 740.334 366.3C728.274 362.777 716.754 352.697 704.553 342.033C682.349 322.618 657.437 300.833 626.427 319.774C579.494 348.444 568.762 457.69 575.941 510.793C578.842 532.242 587.169 562.76 610.391 586.38C635.841 612.262 673.617 624.481 722.685 622.693C879.386 617 971.681 582.217 997.008 519.307C1014.67 475.449 1008.26 420.699 980.687 379.814C976.56 373.657 971.879 367.891 966.702 362.587" fill="url(#paint6_diamond_1354_44250)" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
<path d="M666.911 548.795C651.461 533.081 645.934 512.904 644.019 498.744C639.32 463.972 646.631 389.289 677.362 370.521C696.957 358.547 712.544 372.186 727.613 385.374C735.75 392.489 743.43 399.202 751.66 402.146C752.189 402.335 752.714 402.511 753.251 402.666C774.671 408.969 796.353 401.97 819.312 394.56C836.669 388.959 854.585 383.177 872.965 383.2C884.732 383.216 896.868 388.978 907.14 399.427C910.578 402.948 913.685 406.778 916.422 410.867C934.83 438.16 939.12 474.697 927.345 503.949C910.423 545.982 848.001 569.247 741.815 573.113C709.139 574.292 683.937 566.113 666.911 548.795ZM909.384 397.25C902.612 390.361 895.21 385.449 887.384 382.651C882.764 380.972 877.889 380.1 872.973 380.073C854.089 380.047 835.926 385.908 818.36 391.578C795.868 398.837 774.628 405.693 754.138 399.663C746.008 397.31 738.172 390.455 729.879 383.199C714.49 369.741 697.283 354.69 675.732 367.851C643.406 387.597 635.99 462.677 640.923 499.16C642.921 513.948 648.661 534.992 664.65 551.25C682.155 569.055 708.158 577.459 741.93 576.232C849.462 572.318 912.82 548.391 930.247 505.116C942.396 474.927 937.989 437.247 919.021 409.115C916.179 404.873 912.954 400.901 909.386 397.249" fill="url(#paint7_diamond_1354_44250)" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
<defs>
<radialGradient id="paint0_diamond_1354_44250" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(771.638 408.206) rotate(-22.2423) scale(621.853 517.948)">
<stop stop-color="#3AF062"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#C4B4F9" stop-opacity="0.15"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint1_diamond_1354_44250" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(773.092 415.286) rotate(-22.2423) scale(554.391 461.656)">
<stop stop-color="#3AF062"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#C4B4F9" stop-opacity="0.15"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint2_diamond_1354_44250" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(774.387 422.429) rotate(-22.2423) scale(486.757 405.366)">
<stop stop-color="#3AF062"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#C4B4F9" stop-opacity="0.15"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint3_diamond_1354_44250" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(775.648 429.489) rotate(-22.2423) scale(419.118 348.931)">
<stop stop-color="#3AF062"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#C4B4F9" stop-opacity="0.15"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint4_diamond_1354_44250" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(776.948 436.647) rotate(-22.2423) scale(351.483 292.66)">
<stop stop-color="#3AF062"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#C4B4F9" stop-opacity="0.15"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint5_diamond_1354_44250" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(778.247 443.802) rotate(-22.2423) scale(283.846 236.389)">
<stop stop-color="#3AF062"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#C4B4F9" stop-opacity="0.15"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint6_diamond_1354_44250" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(779.545 450.961) rotate(-22.2423) scale(216.211 180.119)">
<stop stop-color="#3AF062"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#C4B4F9" stop-opacity="0.15"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint7_diamond_1354_44250" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(780.846 458.115) rotate(-22.2423) scale(148.575 123.849)">
<stop stop-color="#3AF062"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#C4B4F9" stop-opacity="0.15"/>
</radialGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

I tried to reduce opacity of the svg path fill to create a similar affect but i was unable to achieve so.